# Firebase Phone auth is not working in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Phone auth is not working. I got an Error that
 "D/err12312: An internal error has occurred. [ Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.firebase.auth.v1.IdentityIdaasAuthenticationService.SendVerificationCode are blocked. ]
"
how to fix this?

Comment: Did you add SHA-1 code to firebase?

Comment: yes! I have added it.

Comment: You can share your code Java and config Authentication firebase console

Comment: My code is working perfectly yesterday. I got this problem after I have enabled the Map places services and adding the billing information.

Comment: This is my Log details :                                                                                D/err12312: An internal error has occurred. [ Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.firebase.auth.v1.IdentityIdaasAuthenticationService.SendVerificationCode are blocked. ]

Answer (score 0):

the line of

```
admin.inializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
```

Initialise with the

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://XYZ.firebaseio.com/',
  storageBucket: 'gs://project-XYZ.appspot.com/'
});
```

method fix the problem.. i hope....

Comment: this piece of code does'nt seem like andorid. i'm working on android

Comment: Phone auth is worked well. But suddenly it gives me error like this. I have enabled the Google cloud places API. after only I'm getting error like this

Comment: did u verified the api ? sometimes these auth are annoying

Comment: https://console.firebase.google.com/?pli=1  <-- do creation from here not from android studio... then replace json files with the new ones.. hope this fix that

Comment: No. My card is not accepted. But, I've got the 300$ credits in my cloud service panel

Comment: D/err12312: An internal error has occurred. [ Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.firebase.auth.v1.IdentityIdaasAuthenticationService.SendVerificationCode are blocked. ]
Still i'm getting this error

Comment: Your card may be the issue.. try it with another card... i had an issue like this once with another api. card was the issue

Comment: Okay. I'll try with another card

Comment: and put a recomended password

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have added restrictions on your Android API key. Try relaxing those from the cloud console UI and then try again.

Comment: Okay I will try that

Comment: I have relaxed the API key. But still getting same error